# Recuperar y/o Resetear Password con yii2

Tags: php, yii2

He seguido un tutorial para poder recuperar la password, envía un correo con un código y un enlace para cambiar la password, se abre un formulario donde se ingresa el email, la nueva password, repetir password, e ingresar el código enviado al email.

Hasta aquí todo ok, al enviar el formulario, aparece el siguiente PHP Warning:
yii\base\ErrorException

> Creating default object from empty value
>
> in /home/claudio/www/servpc-yii/controllers/SiteController.php at line
>   317
>
> Linea 317  $table->password = crypt($model->password,
>   Yii::$app->params["salt"]); despues de esta linea al poner 
>   var_dump($table); die(); Muestra null;

Por favor me pueden ayudar, es gracias.

SiteController.php

```
public function actionResetpass(){

    //Instancia para validar el formulario
    $model = new FormResetPass;

    //Mensaje que será mostrado al usuario
    $msg = null;

    //Abrimos la sesión
    $session = new Session;
    $session->open();

    //Si no existen las variables de sesión requeridas lo expulsamos a la página de inicio
    if (empty($session["recover"]) || empty($session["id_recover"]))
    {
        return $this->redirect(["site/index"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $recover = $session["recover"];
        //El valor de esta variable de sesión la cargamos en el campo recover del formulario
        $model->recover = $recover;

        //Esta variable contiene el id del usuario que solicitó restablecer el password
        //La utilizaremos para realizar la consulta a la tabla users
        $id_recover = $session["id_recover"];
    }

    //Si el formulario es enviado para resetear el password
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        if ($model->validate())
        {
            //Si el valor de la variable de sesión recover es correcta
            if ($recover == $model->recover)
            {
                //Preparamos la consulta para resetear el password, requerimos el email, el id
                //del usuario que fue guardado en una variable de session y el código de verificación
                //que fue enviado en el correo al usuario y que fue guardado en el registro
                $table = Users::findOne(["email" => $model->email, "id" => $id_recover, "verification_code" => $model->verification_code]);
                // var_dump($table);
                // die();
                //Encriptar el password
                //  echo $model->password, "<br/> ";
                //  echo Yii::$app->params['salt'];
                //  exit;  
                $table->password = crypt($model->password, Yii::$app->params["salt"]);

                //Si la actualización se lleva a cabo correctamente
                if ($table->save())
                {
                    //Destruir las variables de sesión
                    $session->destroy();

                    //Vaciar los campos del formulario
                    $model->email = null;
                    $model->password = null;
                    $model->password_repeat = null;
                    $model->recover = null;
                    $model->verification_code = null;

                    $msg = "<p class='alert alert-info'>Password cambiada correctamente, redireccionando a la página de login ...</p>";
                    $msg .= "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; ".Url::toRoute("site/login")."'>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $msg = "<p class='alert alert-error'>Ha ocurrido un error</p>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $model->getErrors();
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render("resetpass", ["model" => $model, "msg" => $msg]);
}

private function randKey($str='', $long=0)
{
    $key = null;
    $str = str_split($str);
    $start = 0;
    $limit = count($str)-1;
    for($x=0; $x<$long; $x++)
    {
        $key .= $str[rand($start, $limit)];
    }
    return $key;
}
```

Echos

```
echo $session["recover"]; f5e28e9a0f7dcbf86c23f8c6fc0ed2d3d1bc6bcc0af3b4287b2d949e603a863ce5fa71de2374e02c1af15f515f24bc7f8cf5429cb76fdf1507cbc837db2eef3c297c27f35c981137f69142f747b9d5b5498c6d61f607ea4364a0c0e7ef71b8d57b84f4b5

echo $session["id_recover"]; Vacio

var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()); /home/claudio/www/servpc-yii/controllers/SiteController.php:314: array (size=2) '_csrf' => string 'FbafSPuM7id79UycANxU3ZvuQJYVYuQxPkrTZ8QMbwt6-fApkfylRi3AAN1Bs2WM7a8F_Gw3nWVQJ5cDimo8Rw==' (length=88) 'FormResetPass' => array (size=5) 'email' => string 'webmaster@servpc.cl' (length=19) 'password' => string '**********' (length=11) 'password_repeat' => string '**********' (length=11) 'verification_code' => string '12252cff' (length=8) 'recover' => string 'f5e28e9a0f7dcbf86c23f8c6fc0ed2d3d1bc6bcc0af3b4287b2d949e603a863ce5fa71de2374e02c1af15f515f24bc7f8cf5429cb76fdf1507cbc837db2eef3c297c27f35c981137f69142f747b9d5b5498c6d61f607ea4364a0c0e7ef71b8d57b84f4b5' (length=200)
```

Comment: puedes añadir el código de SiteController.php o al menos la funciona en la que te encuentras por favor , asi se podrá valorar mejor tu problema , gracias :)

Comment: Gracias Enric, edito el código

Comment: Bueno pues como ves  tu variable de session "id_recover" no esta llena y esto hace que cuando busques a el usuario con el id=$id_recover  no encuentres nada . Busca en tu código donde asignas valor a esa variable de sesión , porque en el código que nos has dado no hay nada .

Comment: Seguí el siguiente tutorial, http://jquery-manual.blogspot.com/2015/02/yii-framework-2-user-recuperar-password.html y revisando los archivos, no encuentro ninguna diferencia